# Why DIV shifts when focus() is invoked in onBeforeDeactivate event handler?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, focus, right-to-left

I met a wired problem for a web page in IE7/8. The page configured to be **dir="rtl"**. And **divRow** is made very large **width** so as its containing div doesn't wrap.

Click the editor area, type some words, then click the "Hello world" text. The layout will  turns to be messy, because the offset and width of div with **divRow** class changed.

I suppose this is a IE7/8 bug.
Is there any way to workaround this?

Basically, ***divRow*** must to have its contained div not wrap.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    div 
    {
      border: 1px;
      border-color: black;
    }

    .divRow
    {
      /* this is to make its containing div not to wrap */
      min-width: 2000px; 
    }

    div.divEditor
    {
      width: 100%;
    }

    iframe
    {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function $(id)
    {
      return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    function focusToRight()
    {
      var elem = $("innerDiv1");

      function fcs()
      {
        elem.focus();
      }
      setTimeout(fcs, 1);

    }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body dir="rtl">
    <div>
    <div id='main' 
      style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width=100%">
      <div class="divRow" id="firstRow">
        <div style='float:right' id='innerDiv1'>
          Hello world.
        </div>
        <div style='float:right' id='innerDiv2'>
          This is to make it is very very very very very very very very  
          very very very very very very very very long
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="divEditor">
        <iframe id="editorIFrame" onbeforedeactivate="focusToRight();" 
          src="about:blank"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    <script>
      //document.getElementById('main').style.width='40px';
      //$("editorIFrame").document.designMode = "on";
      document.frames["editorIFrame"].document.designMode = "On";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the min-width:2000px condition completely.

The way to stop a containing div from wrapping, or collapsing, is to insert an empty div with style="clear:right" just before the end of it. This new div is still inside the containing div, but it must clear, i.e go below, the floats, so it stretches the vertical height of the div.

Comment: It looks work in both IE and Firefox for my code, but I'm told that web browsers may have bugs about this CSS feature. Is it true?

Comment: ie6 can be a little buggy from time to time in how it treats clears but as far as I know ie7 fixed that.

If you notice any problems in ie6 try adding {width:auto;} to the clearing div